# Should I keep an experimental Kubuntu PPA?

Tags: kubuntu, ppa, muon-package-manager

On a recent clean Kubuntu 11.10 64 bit install, Muon Package Manager and Muon Software Update Center would not work. I would just get a bug report.

I had to do all the updates through Konsole. The only way I could get Muon to work was install an experimental version of Muon through a PPA, `ppa:echidnaman/qapt-experimental`.
I am not having problems with the experimental version, it seems to work great.

I am not a fan of experimental software and I know the cons of having an experimental PPA, like breaking the program on an update, but should I keep the experimental PPA or disable it and count on stable updates?

If I disable the experimental PPA will that cause problems of reverting to the release I am having problems with?

Comment: If you want to keep the current version of Muon you have then delete the PPA as you fear of it breaking in a future update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing to say you can't keep the experimental ppa. Personally I would, here's why.

**If the current (stable) Muon is not working and you have a bug report then something is breaking the stable version. This needs to be dealt with and will. As soon as the bug is fixed and you feel more comfortable then revert back to it.**

In the mean time there is always a way to get updates.